# Include javascript code in Thymeleaf on demand

Tags: thymeleaf

is it possible to use thymyleaf conditions for building javascript function ?
For example I have a flag `specialClient` which I will pass from java code to template render engine. So now I want to write something like followed code in my template:

```
...
<th:if=${specialClient}>
callbackForSpecialCLient()
<else>
plainCallbackWithAdForPoorClients
<endif>
...
```

which (after rendering) should result in:

```
...
callbackForSpectialClient()
...
```

As you can see we don't have any if conditions in rendered result. That's what I want so much to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve your desired functionality with following code:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    <th:block th:if="${specialClient}">
        callbackForSpecialCLient();
    </th:block>

    <th:block th:unless="${specialClient}">
        plainCallbackWithAdForPoorClients();
    </th:block>

</script>
```

Comment: Ye I know this solution, but it force me to move callback call from method to another <script>